# How do I add one Observable to another as a value mapped to an ID

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am using RxJS Observables within Angular and cannot work out which operator to use to emit a single stream. I am using types and have one observable that emits this:

```
export interface user {
   id: string,
   name: string,
}
```

And one that emits this:

```
export interface devices {
    type: string,          
    os: string,     
    user_id: string,               
}
```

and am trying to combine them into a single observable that gives me this:

```
export interface user {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    devices: Array <{
        type: string,          
        os: string,     
        user_id: string,               
    }>
}
```

With devices mapped to users based on their user_id.

Answer (score 2):

You need `forkJoin` and an inner pipe to extend the user with his devices.

```
this.usersWithDevices$ = this.myService.getAllUsers().pipe(
  switchMap(users => {
    return forkJoin(users.map(user => {
      return this.myService.getDevicesForUser(user.id).pipe(
        map(devices => ({ ...user, devices })),
      );
    }));
  }),
);
```

Also see my example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-98yygy?file=index.ts

Comment: Wow! That is superb! Thanks so much for taking the time to create that Stackblitz. So with this method a call to the API is made for every user. Is this best practice? Or is it possible to have just two calls and "shuffle" them together? I suppose I am thinking if I needed to add a 3rd or 4th set of data. Thanks so much though - this works really well!

Comment: Your last questions really depend on the case.

Comment: Well, I suppose I have a set of rules that are applied to the device and a separate set of rules applied to the user, so I was thinking rather than run another API call for every user and every client, is it possible just to get ALL of the users, clients and different rules and then shuffle together by their ids, if you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const users$ = of([{id: '1', name: 'John'}, {id: '2', name: 'Peter'}]);
const devices$ = of([{type: 'printer', userId: '1'}, {type: 'scanner', userId: '2'}]);

const result$ = combineLatest([users$, devices$]).pipe(
    map(([users, devices]) => {
        return users.map(user => {
            const devicesForCurrentUser = devices.filter(device => device.userId === user.id);
            return {
                ...user,
                devices: devicesForCurrentUser
            };
        });
    })
);

result$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but I am not sure how this maps a set a data set to a specific id.

Comment: @simecircle I've changed the answer according to your comment. The mapping has nothing to do with rxjs - it's a plain `filter` method of an array

Comment: Awesome! This also works really well! I can't work out which method of the two provided is the best, but I suppose that belies my inexperience.   I think your code is missing a closing bracket though, just FYI. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @simecircle thanks, I've changed the code again to make it work properly with all the brackets on their places. Also, I've changed the `from` to `of` Observable creation function because you are probably expecting an array of users/devices to be fetched beforehand